# How to bring count by pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of account number and corresponding to it i am trying to bring the count of the repeated account number. Below is the sample datasets:

```
a=['2',
'6',
'03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142',
'03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141',
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141',
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142',
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141',
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142',

'5',
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0144',
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142',
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0145',
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0146',
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0143']
```

I tried the below code:

```
import collections
print collections.Counter(a)
```

But it is not giving the result

my desired result should be like this:

```
b=[
'03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142','1'
'03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141','1'
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141','1'
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142','3'
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141','1'
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142','1'
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0144','1'
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142','3'
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0145','1'
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0146','1'
'30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0143','1']
```

Comment: Where does `2`, `5`, `6` go in your expected output and why you tag this with pandas?

Comment: it should not appear in the output

Comment: Your input and output are not (2xn) pandas dataframes, just flat Python lists, is that really what you want? Recommend you start by converting your input to `pd.DataFrame`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've tagged pandas, let's use `.groupby` and `.size`

```
import pandas as pd 


df = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['data'])
values = df.loc[df['data'].str.len() > 1].groupby(
                         ['data'],as_index=False).size().values


array([['03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141', 1],
       ['03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142', 1],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141', 2],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142', 3],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0143', 1],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0144', 1],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0145', 1],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0146', 1]], dtype=object)
```

---

If you want the data with its original index you can use `.groupby` with `.transform` which applies groupby operations without modifying an index.

```
df.assign(val=df.groupby(['data'])['data'].transform('size'))\
         .loc[df['data'].str.len() > 1].values


array([['03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142', 1],
       ['03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141', 1],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141', 2],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142', 3],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141', 2],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142', 3],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0144', 1],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142', 3],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0145', 1],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0146', 1],
       ['30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0143', 1]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `Counter`,

```
from collections import Counter

list(Counter(i for i in a if len(i) > 1).items())
```

---

```
[('03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142', 1),
 ('03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141', 1),
 ('30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141', 2),
 ('30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142', 3),
 ('30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0144', 1),
 ('30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0145', 1),
 ('30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0146', 1),
 ('30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0143', 1)]
```

Comment: I am getting one unusual error "Dataframe constructor not properly called"

Comment: Not sure what your trying to do ?

Comment: Your ouput is perfectly fine. but this is just a dataset i created. My actual input dataset is in this form 2
6
03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142
03 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0141
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142

5
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0144
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0145
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0146
30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0143

Comment: And when i transform this list to dataframe then i am getting the error "Dataframe constructor not properly called"

Comment: May be you might have to edit your question with actual input..